# which of the following vectors are in the span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have been asked to determine whether or not the following vectors are in the span of (1,0,2,1) , (-2,3,-1,1), (2,-2,1,-1)

a)  (1,1,2,1)

b) (1,0,0,0)

c) (0,1,0,0)

d) (0,0,0,0)

so here are my answers, vectors a and d are in the span, however, the vectors b and c are not in the span.

If we wrote down a system of linear equations that corresponds to the vectors, it would look like the one below. (i'll use vector b as an example)

x - 2y + 2z = 1
3y - 2z = 0
2x - y + z = 0
x + y - z = 0

i used gaussian elimination to find the solutions for the system of equations, and the solutions i found are x = -1/3, y = 4/3, z = 2...... however, when i plugged these solutions into the equations above, i got an inconsistency on the fourth equation (1 = 0), which tells me that the vector is not in the span,

did i make any mistakes somewhere? my professor did not give me the solutions to these problems so there's no way i can check if i did this correctly

Comment: It isn't clear where your coefficients are from in the system of linear equations. For example, why does the first equation have $3z$ instead of $2z$? Why does the second equation have $y$ instead of $3y$?

Comment: Sorry, i have corrected the equations.

Comment: That looks better, although I think the last equation should have $-2z$, not $z$. Also, have a look at this [wonderful guide to formatting mathematical expressions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: darn it, i made one last correction to the vectors. It actually is supposed to be -z and not -2z. sorry about that. so do you think i got the correct answers?

Comment: a. is the combination of $1(1,0,2,1) +1 (-2,3,-1,1)+1 (2,-2,1,-1)$\\

b. is not a combination of the given vectors;\\

c. is got with $\{0,\;1,\;1\}$;\\

d. is got with $\{0,\;0,\;0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few observations:

Some of your work is right; some of it isn't. I notice that your system of equations had the wrong coefficients, even after you updated it, so I wonder if you are working too quickly or not paying close attention to the numbers? Unfortunately, with this kind of task, one wrong number will throw everything off.

Also, note that you shouldn't have to do any calculations at all for $(0,0,0,0)$, since this is trivially in the span. (It is $0\Bbb v_1 + 0\Bbb v_2 + 0\Bbb v_3$ where the $\Bbb v_i$ are your given vectors.)

Finally, it doesn't really make sense to say that you solved a system and got $(x,y,z) = (\ldots)$ but that at the same time you found that the system is inconsistent. If the system is inconsistent (which it is in this case), then there is no solution for $x,y,z$.

Comment: Yes you are right, i guess i was working too fast. The process of gaussian elimination should've made it obvious that there were inconsistencies. but my mistake was not finishing the elimination. Thank you very much